# upload image from ionic to express.js multer

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, ionic-framework, multer

i have tried to do this in many way , still no luck  here is my code for ionic framework to upload image (you can simply copy paste it, and run it at android)

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ngCordova'])

.controller('DashCtrl', function ($scope, $cordovaCamera,$cordovaFileTransfer, $http) {


$scope.takePic = function () {
var options = {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: 0, // 0:Photo Library, 1=Camera, 2=Saved Photo Album
    encodingType: 1 // 0=JPG 1=PNG
}
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, options);
}

var onSuccess = function (FILE_URI) {
//console.log(FILE_URI);
$scope.picData = FILE_URI;
//$scope.picData = LZString.compressToUTF16(FILE_URI)
$scope.$apply();
};

var onFail = function (e) {
console.log("On fail " + e);
}

$scope.send = function () {

var options = {
    fileName: $scope.picData.substr($scope.picData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
    chunkedMode: false,
    mimeType: "image/png"
};

console.log($scope.picData);
$cordovaFileTransfer.upload('http://localhost:8001/upload2', $scope.picData, options).then(function (result) {
        console.log("SUCCESS: " + JSON.stringify(result.response));
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    },
    function (progress) {
        console.log(progress);
    });

 }
})
```

i have no problem getting image from library and get the url .
the code below is the server side code where i use multer to do the job .

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var multer = require('multer');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var app = express();



app.use(bodyParser.json({
limit: '50mb'
 }));
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
limit: '50mb',
  extended: true
 }));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
next();
});


var storage = multer.diskStorage({

destination: function (req, file, callback) {
callback(null, './uploads');
console.log('hit storage');
},
filename: function (req, file, callback) {
callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
console.log('hit storage');
 }
});

var upload = multer({
storage: storage
}).single('userPhoto');


app.post('/upload2', function (req, res) {
console.log('hit post');
upload(req, res, function (err) {
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    //console.log(req);
    return res.end("Error uploading file.");
} else {
    console.log('done');
    res.end("File is uploaded");
}

});
});
```

you can simply copy and paste the above code in server.js and test .

and the error i get is this

```
{ [Error: Unexpected field]
code: 'LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE',
field: 'file',
storageErrors: [] }
```

FYI: i use chrome inspect device feature to run the localhost in my android .
(chrome://inspect/#devices).

another thing, why i am getting image url like this

> "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A42"

formate missing , does it make any sense ?

my ionic info

> Your system information:

```
Cordova CLI: 5.4.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.0
ios-deploy version: 1.8.4
ios-sim version: 5.0.4
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v5.7.0
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2.1 Build version 7C1002
```

Comment: passing just the url of the image will not work in multer, it is an extension to body-parser module. Thus, you need to pass the image or file along with request body. And for the `userPhoto` concern remove the `single` tag, as it only allows to upload single photo with name `userPhoto`.  `multer({storage:storage, fileFilter : fileFilter}).any();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this for image uploading:

```
  var fs = require('fs');
      var tmp_path = fs.createReadStream(req.files.image.path);
        var target_path = './public/images/' + req.files.file.name +  randomNumber;

fs.rename(tmp_path, target_path, function(err) {
           // if (err) throw err;

            fs.unlink(tmp_path, function() {
               // if (err) throw err;
                //res.send('File uploaded to: ' + target_path + ' - ' + req.files.file.size + ' bytes');
            });
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue, what I've found digging around is that when using multer we have to make sure the name ('userPhoto' in your case) on this line .single('userPhoto'); matches the name of the file in your html form, the thing is we aren't using html forms to get any image, we take them from the camera with cordova plugin. I tested the endpoint with POSTMAN and it works loading the image in the body of the request and specifying the same name 'userPhoto' as a key. Hope this gets any useful answer soon.